# How to compare Current System date with with another date

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am getting date in string format from API.
`End Date 2014-06-03T06:16:52`. I need to write an if-else logic and compare the end date and current date.If end date is less than current date then show customer as In Active and if end date is greater than display the Customer as Active.
I have tried following logic but I am not able to understand and get today's time in string fromat.

```
  this.endDate = this.sampleData != null ? 
  this.sampleData.customerStartDate : null;
  this.currentDate = new Date();
  var dd = this.currentDate.getDate();
  var mm = this.currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = this.currentDate.getFullYear();
  this.currentDate = new Date().toLocaleString()
  console.log('End Date', this.endDate);
  console.log('Current Date: ', this.currentDate);
  if (this.endDate == null) {
    this.customerStatus = 'Active';
  } else {
    this.customerStatus = 'In Active';
  }
```

I am getting current date as `Current Date:  4/2/2019, 1:23:34 AM` 
I want to be able to get in same format as End Date.
My main task is to compare the dates how do I achieve it ?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to clean up the date you're getting from an API, and convert it to a JS `Date` object. You can do this by keeping only the `2014-06-03T06:16:52` part, and giving it to the `new Date()` constructor.

You can get the current date by calling `new Date()` without parameters.

You can the turn the dates in to numbers by calling `getTime()` on each.

You can then compare the numbers.

```
const incoming_date = new Date('2014-06-03T06:16:52');
const current_date = new Date();
if (incoming_date.getTime() < current_date.getTime() {
    // incoming_date is before current_date
} else {
    // current_date is before incoming_date
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error core.js:12584 ERROR TypeError: _this.endDate.getTime is not a function in my typescript code

Comment: That's because you need to convert `endDate` to a standard valid date first.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ivan Rubinson. I got it working with the help of Moment Library using Aaron Ross's answer initially but like you said we don't need to import heavy dependency so used your method.

Answer (score 0):

as simple as this:

```
let date=new Date("2014-06-03T06:16:52")

date>new Date()
```

Comment: Is the `>` operator overloaded in JS? I think you need to convert the `Date` object in to a number first.

Comment: I was wondering so as well after I saw you post so I double checked with a few variations ans it seems to work  - as far as I know you can "implement" a greater /smaller if you provide a .valueOf() for an object (the valueOf() method of date returns millseconds since epoch so its accurate)

Comment: How is it in terms of browser backwards compatibility?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf browser compatibility on the bottom (I asume the numbers mean since version oO)

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use [moment()](https://momentjs.com/) for javascript dates.  You really just need to have it compare the same format, so you could have something like:

```
this.currentDate = moment().toISOString();
const dataDate = this.sampleData ? this.sampleData.customerStartDate : null;
this.endDate = moment(dataDate).toISOString();
if (this.endDate > this.currentDate) {
    this.customerStatus = 'Active';
} else {
    this.customerStatus = 'Inactive';
}
```

Comment: moment is a large library. There's no reason to bring in such a heavy dependency simply for comparing two dates. It's also monolithic, meaning it can't be made any leaner.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to express dates in ms since the Unix Epoch with `getTime()` and compare them

```
if (currDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime()) {
    // set customer to inactive
} else {
    // keep customer active
}
```